# BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR - TypeError: util.promisify is not a function

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I created a simple Hello World bot. The training wen fine, but when I went to test it in log dialogs it hung. This si what I got in the command window:

> BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR - TypeError: util.promisify is not a function
>   (node:17196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): TypeError: util.promisify is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Grr I should have searched better. I needed to install the latest Node (version 8+). I installed Node (https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and now everything runs fine.